# Python insert SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi

i have the following problem:

i want to insert the temperature of my RPI using SQLite3 and Python.
The python script that i want to use:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sqlite3 as lite
import datetime
import sys
import time

def get_temperature():
    "Returns the temperature in degrees C"
    try:
        s = subprocess.check_output(["cat","/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp"])
        return s[:-1]
    except:
        return 0



try:
    con = lite.connect('/www/auslastung.s3db')
    cur = con.cursor()

    temp = int(get_temperature())
    zeit = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'temperatur' ('Wert', 'Zeit') VALUES (%s, %s)", (temp, zeit))

    con.commit()

except lite.Error, e:

    if con:
       con.rollback()
    print "Error %s" % e.args[0]
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
       con.close()
```

Every time i want to run this, i just get the error:

```
Error near "%": syntax error
```

What should i do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'temperatur' ('Wert', 'Zeit') VALUES (%s, %s)", (temp, zeit))
```

with

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'temperatur' ('Wert', 'Zeit') VALUES (?, ?)", (temp, zeit))
```

There is also a problem with your `finally` clause. It will fail with the error `NameError: name 'con' is not defined` if `con` is never assigned to in the first place (e.g., if the directory `/www/` does not exist, so `con = lite.connect('/www/auslastung.s3db')` fails). You could do the following to avoid this issue:

```
con = None
try:
    # ...
except lite.Error, e:
    if con is not None:
       con.rollback()
    # ...
finally:
    if con is not None:
       con.close()
```

Comment: its worth noting this is only in the `sqlite`  connector ... the other ones(mysql,postgres,etc) typically do use `%s` ... also if the db file does not exists the sqlite library creates it (all the same +1)

Comment: @JoranBeasley You're correct; I'll edit my answer. It will fail if, say, the path to the file does not exist or you can't write to it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! As you can imagine i used this script to insert data in mysql but i moved to sqlite. Now i get the NameError even that i use "is not None"

Comment: saw you updated answer: the python script is in /var/ and the DB is in /www/ and the name is correct. My assumption is to point at the db this way, or is it wrong?

Comment: @cYnd Where do you get the `NameError`? Do you assign `None` to `con` before the `try` block?

Comment: damn! yeah, you were right! I didn't assignet None to con before the try, sorry! And NOW i get the error you predicted: "Error unable to open database file" :(

Comment: @cYnd Is the database file there? Try `sqlite3 /www/auslastung.s3db` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace:

cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'temperatur' ('Wert', 'Zeit') VALUES (%s, %s)", (temp, zeit))

with

cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'temperatur' ('Wert', 'Zeit') VALUES (%s, %s)" % (temp, zeit))

Either @nwk or my answer should work depending on preference.

Comment: this is not the right way to do it ... the other method protects against sql injection (although I guess i will remove my downvote since in this use case there is no untrusted input) ... but in general you shouldnt do that